# input hexadecimal number using Unsigned Char Array

Tags: c++

I am having problem inputting hexadecimal number using unsigned char array. 
Code:

```
unsigned char key[16];
for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++){
    cin>>key[i];
}
```

It takes single character as one character e.g. - 0x1b is read as 0 x 1 b separately. Please help me.

Comment: are you aware how many char are in ***0x1b*** when you use the cin to give that input?

Comment: Please take the time to read [ask] a question. In particular, please specify how it isn't working, what is intended and what is the result

Comment: There are 4 char in 0x1b and this code also takes it separately.

Answer (score 1):

You can use std::hex.

```
unsigned int hex = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    std::cin >> std::hex >> hex;
    key[i] = hex;
}
```